# Ghostscript - Error: ignoring recursive /SMask attribute, output might be incorrect

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm having trouble splitting a pdf page in half.
Normally I do this for over 100 different sized pdf's a month. But I've come across some that is giving me errors.

Extracted pdf-pages: [195.pdf](http://skorpion.se/images/195.pdf)

In my current pdf, it is on page 195 and I've extracted that page with:

```
gs -o 195.pdf -dFirstPage=195 -dLastPage=195 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/None original_file.pdf
```

This pdf (195.pdf) has page-size:

```
3152.13 x 612.28 pts
```

So when splitting it in half I use:

```
gs -o left_sections.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/None -g15760x6122 -c "<</PageOffset [0 0]>> setpagedevice" -f 195.pdf
```

And this produces the following error:

```
Page 1
**** Error: ignoring recursive /SMask attribute.
           Output may be incorrect.
**** Error: ignoring recursive /SMask attribute.
           Output may be incorrect.
**** Error: ignoring recursive /SMask attribute.
           Output may be incorrect.
**** Error: ignoring recursive /SMask attribute.
           Output may be incorrect.

**** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
**** The file was produced by: 
**** >>>> GPL Ghostscript 9.19 <<<<
**** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
**** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
**** specification.

**** The rendered output from this file may be incorrect.
```

The only difference that I can visually see in the created left_sections.pdf to the original is a small horizontal stripe at the top & bottom-right corners.

My version of ghostscript is 9.19

Any ideas what can cause this or how to resolve this?

Best Regards
Niclas Rådström

Answer (score 1):

OK so first thing to notice is that Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device do not 'split' PDF files, nor merge them or anything which might imply the resulting PDF file has anything much to do with the original PDF file.

The PDF file has (as the error says) a recursive SMask, that is the SMask references itself, which is not really going to work well. an example from the file is :

```
31 0 obj

<<
  /Subtype /Image
  /ColorSpace /DeviceGray
  /Width 71
  /Height 2700
  /BitsPerComponent 8
  /Length 191700
  /SMask 31 0 R
>>
```

So you can see the image uses an SMask, which is the same as the actual image, so that's infinitely recursive, which is why Ghostscript complains about it.

Once you get into that situation, the damage is done, there's no way to guarantee recovery from that.

Now what you've posted is a PDF which has been produced by Ghostscript itself, so its not obvious whether the problem was in the original file, or that pdfwrite has produced a file which is invalid. My guess is the latter.

There's really nothing you can do except try the most recent release (9.20) to see if its been fixed (doubtful, I don't recall such a bug report) and/or report a bug. If you do report a bug you will need to supply a sample file, it will get way more attention if you can find a simple file to reproduce it, ie not a many page file.....